# Marcar tabla según condición

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas en **MySQL**:

Tabla: *t_saldos*: `PK(COD)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y Tabla: *t_detalle*: `PK(ID)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito poner una *X* en el campo ***FLG*** de *t_detalle* para todos los códigos cuya suma de los campos ***IMPORTE*** sea menor o igual al valor del campo ***TOTAL*** de *t_saldos*.

Como ejemplo he marcado los que cumplen la condición para ***COD*** = 11.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En *t_saldos* el ***COD*** 11 tiene un valor en ***TOTAL*** de 50.
Entonces la suma de los importes de ***COD*** en *t_detalle* no debe pasar de ese valor, por eso solo se marca hasta el acumulado de 47.
Lo mismo debe hacer para cada registro de *t_saldos*.

Nota: Inicialmente el campo ***flg*** está vacía.

**ACTUALIZACION:**

Creo que la solución sería hacer un cursor en un store procedure. Algo así:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS marcador//
CREATE PROCEDURE marcador()
BEGIN

  DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT cod, total FROM t_saldos;
  DECLARE suma INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  bucle: LOOP

    UPDATE t_detalle SET FLG = 'X' WHERE cod = CURSOR.cod;

    suma = suma + importe;

    IF suma <= CURSOR.total THEN
      LEAVE bucle;
    END IF;

  END LOOP bucle;
  CLOSE cursor;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Me he guiado de unos ejemplos, pero no doy con la ruta correcta.

Comment: Que as intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: yo no entiendo.. estas hablando de la suma total, o de la suma hasta cierto punto... no es nada claro que quere.s...

Comment: Es la suma parcial, solo hasta no exceder el valor de `t_saldos`. (Agregué más información a la pregunta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás buscando algo así:

```
SET @codigo:=0;
SET @t:=0;

UPDATE t_detalle JOIN t_saldos USING(cod)
  JOIN (
    SELECT id,cod,
      IF(@codigo!=cod,@t:=0,@t),
      if(@codigo!=cod,@codigo:=cod,@codigo),
      @t:=@t+importe acumulado
      FROM t_detalle
      ORDER BY cod,id  
  ) c1 USING(id)
  set flg=1
  WHERE acumulado<=total;
```

Para este dataset de muestra:

```
CREATE TABLE t_saldos(
  cod int,
  total float
  );
CREATE TABLE t_detalle(
  id int,
  cod int,
  importe float,
  flg bool
  );
INSERT INTO t_saldos (cod, total) VALUES
(11,50),(22,70),(33,40),(44,80);
INSERT INTO t_detalle (id,cod,importe,flg) VALUES
(1,11,20,1),(2,22,30,0),(3,11,12,1),(4,33,10,0),
(5,22,8,0),(6,44,12,0),(7,11,15,1),(8,11,20,0);
```

Y no necesitas ni el procedimiento almacenado ni el cursor. Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.

Comment: Antes de ejecutar el update puse el valor 0 a todos los flg. Y al ejecutar el update no actualiza ninguno.

Comment: Agregué los **PK**, ejecuté el `UPDATE` pero no actualiza. [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rfvWyusQd4anPMEkSpE1KQ/0)

Comment: Inicializa las variables y te funcionará. He modificado la respuesta para que veas cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Y podrías explicar el funcionamiento, no había visto el `USING`.

Comment: El `USING` es un `ON` abreviado en donde coincide el nombre del campo en ambas tablas

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes MySQL 8 puedes usar una *función de ventana* para calcular el acumulado:

```
UPDATE t_detalle d
  INNER JOIN t_saldos s
    ON d.cod = s.cod
  INNER JOIN ( SELECT d.id
                    , d.cod
                    , sum(d.importe) over( partition by cod order by id ) acum
                 FROM t_detalle d
             ) a
     ON     a.cod = s.cod        
        AND a.acum <= s.total
        AND a.id = d.id
    SET flg = 'X';
```

Puedes ver su funcionamiento en [este fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nsrriviQBFZxJ4kRXjTgm4/0).

Comment: Si funciona en el Finddle pero yo tengo MySQL 5.5.