# Marcar registros en una tabla según el valor de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

En MySQL tengo dos tablas:

**t_saldos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y,

**t_detalle**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero marcar en el campo *FLG* los registros de cada *COD* siempre y cuando la suma de *IMPORTE* contenga al valor del campo *TOTAL*.

Por ejemplo para el *COD* = 11

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso la suma de los 4 primeros registros de *COD* = 11 dan 67 y este valor contiene a 50 que es el valor de *TOTAL* de la tabla **t_saldos**.

Las tablas están en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckReHGdbUN9dAjCk3cBvhs/0)

Utilicé un proceso de una [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/549004)

```
SET @codigo:=0;
SET @t:=0;
UPDATE t_detalle JOIN t_saldos USING(cod)
  JOIN (
    SELECT id,cod,
      IF(@codigo!=cod,@t:=0,@t),
      if(@codigo!=cod,@codigo:=cod,@codigo),
      @t:=@t+importe acumulado
      FROM t_detalle
      ORDER BY cod,id  
  ) c1 USING(id)
  set flg=1
  WHERE acumulado<=total;   <-- NO ME SIRVE Si es >= marca desde valor mayor, y TAMPOCO si es <= marca los menores pero no marca el que contiene la suma.
```

Pero creo que en el WHERE es donde se complica el asunto.

**ACTUALIZACION:**
Inicialmente el campo FLG tiene el valor 0.
Y quiero marcar con 1 los que cumplan con la condición.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Actualicé pregunta con el proceso que he probado.

Comment: @Puntay a ver si entendi, queres marcar todos los registros de la tabla `t_detalle` cuya suma sea MAYOR o IGUAL al `total` en la tabla `t_saldos`, correcto? ¿Y en el caso contrario habría que desmarcarlos?

Comment: Inicialmente e campo `FLG` de la tabla *t_detalle* no tiene marca. Y lo que quiero es que se marque por cada `COD` hasta que el total contenga el valor de ese mismo `COD` de la tabla *t_saldos*.  Por eso puse el ejemplo con el `COD`=11.

Comment: Lei las dos preguntas.. y para mi, estas preguntando otra vez lo mismo.. es mas.. la primera vez que la vi, dije es la misma.. podes aclarar en que se diferencian?

Comment: Los registros marcados. En el ejemplo del anterior para cod=11 solo marca 3 registros. En esta pregunta debe marcar 4 registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar una columna donde controlas si el acumulado en `@t` es menor al `total`.

**Ejemplo:**

```sql
SET @codigo:=0;
SET @t:=0;
SELECT 
    D.id,
    D.cod,
    IF(@codigo!=D.cod, @t:=0, @t),
    IF(@codigo!=D.cod, @codigo:=D.cod, @codigo),
    IF(@t<S.total, 1, 0) AS esMenor, # <- ANTES de sumar el actual
    @t:=@t+D.importe AS acumulado
FROM t_detalle AS D
    JOIN t_saldos AS S
    USING(cod)
ORDER BY D.cod, D.id
```

**Resultado:**

| id | cod | IF(@codigo!=D.cod, @t:=0, @t) | IF(@codigo!=D.cod, @codigo:=D.cod, @codigo) | esMenor | acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 0 | 11 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 11 | 20 | 11 | 1 | 32 |
| 7 | 11 | 32 | 11 | 1 | 47 |
| 8 | 11 | 47 | 11 | 1 | 67 |
| 11 | 11 | 67 | 11 | 0 | 91 |
| 2 | 22 | 0 | 22 | 1 | 30 |
| 5 | 22 | 30 | 22 | 1 | 38 |
| 9 | 22 | 38 | 22 | 1 | 80 |
| 14 | 22 | 80 | 22 | 0 | 90 |
| 4 | 33 | 0 | 33 | 1 | 10 |
| 10 | 33 | 10 | 33 | 1 | 40 |
| 15 | 33 | 40 | 33 | 0 | 52 |
| 6 | 44 | 0 | 44 | 1 | 12 |
| 12 | 44 | 12 | 44 | 1 | 52 |
| 16 | 44 | 52 | 44 | 0 | 65 |
| 13 | 55 | 0 | 55 | 1 | 35 |
| 17 | 55 | 35 | 55 | 0 | 51 |

Luego podes utilizar `esMenor = 1` para saber cuáles marcar.

**Solución:**

```sql
SET @codigo:=0;
SET @t:=0;
UPDATE t_detalle AS D
  JOIN (
SELECT 
    D.id,
    D.cod,
    IF(@codigo!=D.cod, @t:=0, @t),
    IF(@codigo!=D.cod, @codigo:=D.cod, @codigo),
    IF(@t<S.total, 1, 0) AS esMenor,
    @t:=@t+D.importe AS acumulado
FROM t_detalle AS D
    JOIN t_saldos AS S
    USING(cod)
ORDER BY D.cod, D.id
    ) T USING(id)
SET D.flg=1
WHERE T.esMenor = 1;
```

**Resultado:**

```
SELECT * FROM t_detalle ORDER BY cod, id;
```

| id | cod | importe | flg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 20 | 1 |
| 3 | 11 | 12 | 1 |
| 7 | 11 | 15 | 1 |
| 8 | 11 | 20 | 1 |
| 11 | 11 | 24 | 0 |
| 2 | 22 | 30 | 1 |
| 5 | 22 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 22 | 42 | 1 |
| 14 | 22 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | 33 | 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 33 | 30 | 1 |
| 15 | 33 | 12 | 0 |
| 6 | 44 | 12 | 1 |
| 12 | 44 | 40 | 1 |
| 16 | 44 | 13 | 0 |
| 13 | 55 | 35 | 1 |
| 17 | 55 | 16 | 0 |

Comment: Agregué más registros a la tabla para probar, pero falla en los `COD` 33 y 55, toma de más. Puedes [verlo aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckReHGdbUN9dAjCk3cBvhs/2)

Comment: @Puntay, solo tenes que cambiar el `<=` por `<`. Actualice mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Considera que el acumulado realmente nunca es cero, por lo menos vale el importe del registro actual.

Con esta consulta puedes determinar el valor de `flg`:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.cod
     , s.total
     , d.importe
     , @suma := d.importe
              + if( @cod = d.cod
                  , @suma
                  , (@cod:=d.cod)-@cod
                  ) suma
     , @suma < (s.total+d.importe) flg
  FROM t_detalle d
    JOIN t_saldos s
      ON s.cod = d.cod
    JOIN (SELECT @suma:=0, @cod:='') v
  ORDER BY d.cod
         , d.id;
```

Y utiliza `flg` para hacer el JOIN en el UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t_detalle d
  JOIN ( SELECT d.id
              , @suma := d.importe
                       + if( @cod = d.cod
                           , @suma
                           , (@cod:=d.cod)-@cod
                           ) suma
              , @suma < (s.total+d.importe) flg
           FROM t_detalle d
             JOIN t_saldos s
               ON s.cod = d.cod
             JOIN (SELECT @suma:=0, @cod:='') v
           ORDER BY d.cod
                  , d.id
        ) t
     ON    t.id = d.id
       AND t.flg = 1
    SET d.flg = 1;
```